# Does there exist a language which is PSPACE-complete and regular?

Tags: complexity-theory

> Does there exist a language which is PSPACE-complete and regular?  (reduction is polynomial with regard to time).

Correct answer here is "unknown".  I can't prove it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a PSPACE-complete regular language if and only if P=PSPACE, which is unknown.

In fact, we can say even more: the language $\{1\}$ is PSPACE-complete if and only if P=PSPACE.

Comment: Is it about that each regular language is in $P$ ?

Comment: This is definitely part of the matter.